# svg pie chart with percentages inside

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is it possible to create a pie chart using SVG with the percentage displayed inside the circles.

I know we can create pie charts using SVG like below, but not sure how to position or display the percentage text. Please help.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3f51b5; 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
 
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 32;
  r: 16;
  cx: 16;
  cy: 16;
}
 
circle.first {
  stroke: #00bcd4;
 
}
 le.second {
  stroke: #ffeb3b;
}
  
circle.third {
  stroke: purple;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <circle class='first' stroke-dasharray="34 100"></circle>
  <circle class='second' stroke-dasharray="36 100"></circle>
  <circle class='third' stroke-dasharray="3 100"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Better to use libraries such as `d3` or `highCharts`

Comment: I don't want to use a big library for this because my requirement is only to display this graph, and also I am able to create the pie chart as above but not sure how to display the percentage text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider `text` element and adjust their position:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3f51b5; 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
svg text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-size:5px;
}
 
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 32;
  r: 16;
  cx: 16;
  cy: 16;
}
 
circle.first {
  stroke: #00bcd4;
 
}
circle.second {
  stroke: #ffeb3b;
}
  
circle.third {
  stroke: purple;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <circle class='first' stroke-dasharray="34 100"></circle>
  <circle class='second' stroke-dasharray="36 100"></circle>
  <circle class='third' stroke-dasharray="3 100"></circle>
  <text x="5" y="-11" fill="#fff">65%</text>
  <text x="15" y="-26" fill="#fff">5%</text>
  <text x="18" y="-17" fill="#fff">35%</text>
</svg>
```